# Improve performance of a query calculating 7 day rolling averages over a large dataset in MS-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a large table of 300,000 records with one of the fields being a date only field and another col, being purchase count. I need to run seven rolling day averages (well six actually) for each day into another table. Any purchase date or figure can alter so I can't just use existing data.

What I am doing is looping through each day from day 1 of sales via VBA creating a and then executing a query with a dsum and updating the summary table so the initial query looks like...

```
  Select dsum(purchases)/7 from purchases as rollingAvg7 where purchaseDate between #01/11/2020# and #07/11/2020#
```

To run these queries takes about two minutes each. Is there a better quicker way of doing this please?

Comment: try replacing dsum() with sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, string expressions for date values cannot have the dd/mm/yyyy format. Use the *ISO sequence* which works everywhere including ADO.

Next, the average can be found directly using *Avg* if the purchases are the totals for each day:

```sql
select avg(purchases)
from purchases as rollingAvg7 
where purchaseDate between #2020/11/01# and #2020/11/07#
```

If you have the individual purchases - returning more than one record per day - use `sum / 7`.

Comment: And of course a index on purchase date would also help!

Comment: Thank you Gustav and @AlbertD.Kallal The index was missing (my mistake in not checking all the indexes first) and just adding the date index dropped the process from six to eight minutes to around 20-30 seconds! The SQL is much more logical as well and have altered this as well.